# SQL Server Import Wizard doesn't import Excel file in sorted order

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have SQL Server Express 17.7 on my computer and I'm trying to import an Excel 97-2003 file with 62,000 rows into a SQL table that's already been created in SQL Server, using the 32-bit Import\Export Wizard.

It fails about 57,000 records in with a truncation error that I'm working to sort out but I noticed that it the records that are successfully imported are not in the sorted order of the Excel spreadsheet.  I first ordered them in Excel on the first column which is a date column.  Then I inserted an INT counter column and sorted on that in Excel and tried importing.  When you view the imported rows in SQL it starts around Excel row# 43,000 then after 225 rows it starts at row#1 from Excel.

This may be old news to others but was news to me.  Should I assume SQL will not import Excel, CSV, TAB, etc in the pre-sorted order?  Or is this a side-effect of not successfully importing the whole file?

Comment: Once imported into a table in SQL Server, order is not guaranteed unless you specify an order by clause.   You would have to have a "row number" in your data that then flows into your table in SQL Server at time of import if you are trying to related a specific row of data in your table back to a row in your excel file.

Comment: Yes, I know order is not guaranteed in a set and you have to specify it.  I'm asking about the SSIS import process specifically, and should I assume it's not going to import rows sequentially from a data source.

Comment: I haven't run into a situation where is hasn't.  We'll usually inject a row number via a script component and whenever we've gone back and validated row by row it was correct, meaning SSIS was importing based on order of the file.